# Importing Activity Error '1' is not a valid option for field custom_133

Tags: activities, upload

When i try and import activities I get the following error message  '1' is not a valid option for field custom_133 across all 5 activities that I am trying to import.

By a process of elimination it is the 'details' field that is causing the problem. Within that field we have a lot of free-flow text copy- paste  of emails and stuff like we have 115 similar activities to upload that therefore hunting within them to eliminate what ever is cause the problem isn't an option.

Is there a simple solution to this.

Thanks

William

Answer (score 1):

What is the field type of the custom_133 field? I'm guessing it is an option group/ select list type of field. In that case, you would have to make sure that the value of the field you are supplying in the import matches to either of the option values that the field has.

HTH,
Edsel

Comment: Hi Edsel Thank-you for your answer, the field in question is the 'details' section of an activity, therefore I think that it is html/rich text. Though I am not sure. Regards